# Minimize weighted $l_1$ loss

Tags: regression, optimization, linear-algebra

It is known that the minimizer of $l_1$ loss function is the sample median, i.e.,
$$\operatorname{argmin}_{x_0}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-x_0| = \operatorname{median}(x_1,...,x_n)$$

assume that I have a vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|w\|_2 = 1$. What would be the minimizer of
$$\operatorname{argmin}_{x_0}\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2|x_i-x_0| $$

I've tried stating that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2|x_i-x_0|  \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-x_0|$ or that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2|x_i-x_0|  \leq \max_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-x_0|$

then optimizing the second term, but it is giving me two completely different answers, I don't think that's the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In effect you are looking for a weighted median.  The following algorithm should work:

1. Order the $x_i$s so you have an increasing sequence $x_{(1)} \le  x_{(2)} \le \cdots \le x_{(n)}$
2. Consider the partial sums $s_j= \sum_{i=1}^j w_{(i)}^2$ using the weights corresponding to the $x_{(i)}$s, and your  $\|w\|_2 = 1$ should give $s_n=1$ though this is not essential.  You should also have $s_0=0$
3. If there is a $k$ such that $s_{k-1} \lt  \frac12 s_n \lt s_{k}$ then you will have your minimiser $x_0=x_{(k)}$
4. Otherwise there will be one or more $k$ with $s_k=\frac12 s_n$; call the smallest $l$ and the biggest $m$ (probably $l=m$, especially if all the $w_i$ are positive).  Then all values in the interval $[x_{(l)}, x_{(m+1)}]$ will minimise the expression

If all the $w_i$ are equal, e.g. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, then this should give you the usual median